# what's basic difference between JsonStore and JsonReader in context to Ext.data?

Tags: json, extjs, jsonreader

What's basic difference between JsonStore and JsonReader in context to Ext.data?

I mean when I should go for JsonStore and when I should use JsonReader as for me both are providing same solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually they are two separate things. A [`Ext.data.JsonReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader) reads a given JSON object and returns data records ([`Ext.data.Record`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Record) objects) that are later stored by the respective data store.

The [`Ext.data.Store`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store) is the base class for all Ext storages and uses helper objects for retrieving data ([`Ext.data.DataProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataProxy)), for writing data ([`Ext.data.DataWriter`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataWriter)) and for reading data ([`Ext.data.DataReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader)). These base classes come in different flavors such as:

- [`Ext.data.DataProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataProxy):

  - [`Ext.data.DirectProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DirectProxy)
  - [`Ext.data.HttpProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.HttpProxy)
  - [`Ext.data.MemoryProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.MemoryProxy)
  - [`Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy)
- [`Ext.data.DataWriter`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DataWriter)

  - [`Ext.data.JsonWriter`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonWriter)
  - [`Ext.data.XmlWriter`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlWriter)
- [`Ext.data.DataReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader)

  - [`Ext.data.JsonReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader)
  - [`Ext.data.XmlReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlReader)

This all builds up to a very extendable component that allows the developer to configure exactly what he needs to tweak. To make it easier for developers (especially new ones) Ext comes with some pre-configured data stores:

- [`Ext.data.ArrayStore`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ArrayStore) to make reading from simple Javascript arrays easier
- [`Ext.data.DirectStore`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DirectStore), just a store preconfigured with an [`Ext.data.DirectProxy`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.DirectProxy) and an [`Ext.data.JsonReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader)
- [`Ext.data.JsonStore`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore), just a store preconfigured with an [`Ext.data.JsonReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonReader)
- [`Ext.data.XmlStore`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlStore), just a store preconfigured with an [`Ext.data.XmlReader`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.XmlReader)

So actually a [`Ext.data.JsonStore`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore) is just a convenience class to make it easier for the developer.

The following two snippets will create the same (or comparable) stores:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: 'get-images.php',
    root: 'images',
    idProperty: 'name',
    fields: ['name', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date'}]
});

// or 

var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: 'get-images.php',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'images',
        idProperty: 'name',
        fields: ['name', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date'}]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A `JsonReader` reads JSON from a data source into an Ext Store.  JsonData is not a specifically-defined Ext object, although maybe you've seen it as a variable name?  In what context are you using it?

Comment: Here is an Example,
Example using Reader
    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        url: '/db?cmd=list'
  }),  
  reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(
    {root: 'row', fields:['name']}
  )
 });
store.load();

Example two with JsonStore

var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
       url: '/db?cmd=list',
       root: 'row',
       fields: ['name']
      });
    store.load();

Comment: Just as a note, you originally asked the difference between JsonReader and *JsonData*, which obviously was a typo since you've edited your question to change that (without noting it).  Just wanted to clarify so that my answer does not look so random.  As Stefan explains below, JsonStore is a convenience class.  If you are loading JSON via HTTP, it simply saves you some configuration effort, but it is equivalent to using a JsonReader plus an HttpProxy.