# Ext JS - Store vs. JsonStore

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

After comparing the documentation of the two classes, I am curious as to why one would use Ext.data.JsonStore as opposed to its superclass: Ext.data.Store. The documentation states the following about JsonStore:

> Small helper class to make creating Ext.data.Stores from JSON data easier. A JsonStore will be automatically configured with a Ext.data.reader.Json.

The documentation then shows the typical configuration of a JsonStore as the following:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // store configs
    autoDestroy: true,
    storeId: 'myStore',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'get-images.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'images',
            idProperty: 'name'
        }
    },

    //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
    fields: ['name', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date'}]
});
```

The above code explicitly sets the reader type to 'json' - wouldn't the json type be implied in a JsonStore? This configuration doesnt seem any different to me than the way someone would configure a proxy to read a JSON file in an instance of Ext.data.Store.

Am I misunderstanding the use of Ext.data.JsonStore? If not, what is the benefit of using it over Ext.data.Store?

Thanks!

Comment: `Ext.data.JsonStore` is just a store preconfigured with an `Ext.data.JsonReader`, so actually a `Ext.data.JsonStore` is just a convenience class to make it easier for the developer. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2132418/2667065).

Comment: I do it for one reason only: Readability. Everyone can deduce what a JsonStore does.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the definition of [`Ext.data.JsonStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/source/JsonStore.html#Ext-data-JsonStore):

```
Ext.define('Ext.data.JsonStore',  {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.json',
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = Ext.apply({
            proxy: {
                type  : 'ajax',
                reader: 'json',
                writer: 'json'
            }
        }, config);
        this.callParent([config]);
    }
});
```